# Оптимизация таблицы Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Доброго всем!
Необходимо оптимизировать выполнение запроса - выборка с несколькими JOIN-ами и несколькими условиями (сам запрос менять нельзя). Есть ли утилита, которая дает рекомендации по созданию индексов в таблице?
Спасибо всем.

Comment: Индексировать надо те поля, по которым производится выборка, в т.ч. и джойнами. Если сомневаетесь в том, что сделали, проведите АБ тестирование.

Answer (score 2):

[EXPLAIN — Самая мощная команда MySQL](http://habrahabr.ru/post/31129/)